# Elastic Search how to structure post filter terms

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to filter only my search results, I have multiple filters I want to dynamically add.

My filters are a list of field names and field values

e.g.

```
   public class filter
    {
        public string val{ get; set; }
        public string field{ get; set; }

    }
```

I get to the part where I need to add the post filter terms but I don't know how to structure it.

```
  List<TermQuery> tl = new List<TermQuery>();
        foreach (var item in filters)
        {
            TermQuery t = new TermQuery();
            t.Field = item.field;
            t.Value = item.val;

            tl.Add(t);
        }

var catSearch= client.Search<dynamic>(s => s.From(from).Size(20).Source(x => x.Query(
            q => q.Bool(
                b => b.Must(
                    l => l.Terms(
                        t => t.Name("KEYWORDS").Field("KEYWORDS").Terms(terms)))).PostFilter(f => f.Terms(l=> {

          //Need to add values and field names to post filter here

          //Add tl here as the post filters

             return l;
         })));
```

I had a look a [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-query-usage.html) but I still dont understand how to dynamically add post filters

Please help me structure the post filter dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have any aggregations in your search request - do you mean to use `post_filter`, or simply build a compound query that includes queries in a filter context?

Comment: The latter, I'm trying to filter only returned results. For example, 6 out of 20 results has a value true for a given field. Id like to get the subset of that results where the field is true, and then again get another subset on that subset

Comment: @RussCam I'm simply trying to filter on the results that are returned and not all the results.